# time complexity of iterating over an avl tree using nextInOrder

Tags: c, time-complexity, avl-tree

Let's say we have a binary `AVL-tree` that each node holds a pointer to the parent.
We also have a function that gives us the next item `inorder`, called `treeSuccesor`.
We can assume that its time complexity is `O(log(N))`.
What will be the time complexity of iterating over the tree with it, starting from the lowest value, and ending at the highest value

For the given `AVL-tree`, what will be the time complexity of iterating over it from the 17's node to 85's node using the `treeSuccesor` function?
[image]

iteration algorithm:

```
while (L != L2) // L2 is the ending node, 85 in the image
{
   L = treeSuccesor(L);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Traversing any binary tree can be done in time `O(n)` since each link is passed twice: once going downwards and once going upwards. For each node the work is constant.

The complexity is not `O(n log n)` because even though the work of finding the next node is `O(log n)` in the worst case for an AVL tree (for a general binary tree it is even `O(n)`), the *average* work over all the nodes in the tree is constant.

Comment: and why is it constant?

Comment: @coco.shot The average? Because we pass each link twice, in total about 2*n, so the average over n is 2. Try to draw the path of traversing the tree and you will see that the total length is about 2*n.